# Restlet Servlet Context Always Null

Tags: tomcat, servlets, restlet, context.xml

I am really frustrated, because since three days I didnt make any progress on this problem.

I have a Restlet Servlet embedded in a Tomcat v7.0 Server. Everything works as expected, except accessing the ServletContext.

**My aim is to read a file, lying in WEB-INF, just at the location the web.xml can be found.**

```
Deployment Resources
WebContent
    log
    META-INF
    WEB-INF
        lib
        textFileToRead.txt <-----
        web.xml
```

To reach this aim i need to access the ServletContext. I tried every codesnipped I could found via web, event those who I wasnt expected to work, due to the fact **I am using Restlet 2.0 je**e and some examples are made for Restlet 1.0 jee.

**Here is how I try to access context:**

```
Context c = this.getContext();
```

I debugged it and made a Screenshop of the variable "c" from above:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b31a52l3w8xifgg/context_full.PNG?dl=0

**As you can see "context" Variable of "ServerDispatcher" is null. But there is a "componentContext", which contains the ServletContext I need so bad. But I dont see a possibility to get access to it.**

---

**Here are some Infos about my configuration**

1. **web.xml**

   ```
    <display-name>MyRestServer</display-name>
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>MyServer</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
           <param-value>com.example.my.server.MyMainComponent</param-value>
       </init-param>

       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <context-param>
       <param-name>myParam</param-name>
       <param-value>the value</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>MyServer</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. **pom.xml**

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>MyRestServer</groupId>
       <artifactId>MyRestServer</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>war</packaging>
       <name>YaynoRestServer</name>
       <description>Maven POM von MyRestServer</description>
       <build>
           <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.1</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>1.8</source>
                       <target>1.8</target>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>        
                   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.4</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                       <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>

       <repositories>
           <repository>
               <id>maven-restlet</id>
               <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
               <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
           </repository>
       </repositories>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
               <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.1</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
               <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.1</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
               <version>1.2.17</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
               <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.1</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
               <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.1</version>
           </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
               <version>1.9.13</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
               <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
               <version>3.0</version>
           </dependency>


       </dependencies>
   </project>
   ```
3. **Structure of Source**

So basically the MyMainComponent creates a Default Host with MyMainApplication

```
    public class MyMainComponent extends Component {
        public YaynoMainComponent() {
            // Starting Application
            getDefaultHost().attachDefault(new MyMainApplication(questionManager.getQuestionPool(), userManager.getUserpool()));
        }
    }

    public class MyMainApplication extends Application {
        @Override
        public Restlet createInboundRoot() {

        // attach routes
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        //router attachments...

        ComponentServerDispatcher c = (ComponentServerDispatcher) this.getContext().getServerDispatcher();

        return router; //breakpoint here to read out c-variable in debugger
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use the client protocol `war` of Restlet. It's automatically registered in the context of a Restlet application embedded within a servlet container. To use it, simply try something like that:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(
        "war:///WEB-INF/textFileToRead.txt");
Representation fileContent = cr.get();
FileRepresentation fileRepresentation
        = new FileRepresentation(fileContent);

// Get stream on the file
FileInputStream fis = fileRepresentation.getStream();
// Get file content as text
String fileContentAsText = fileRepresentation.getText();
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Unfortunately it doesnt work, as the variable:

Representation fileContent = cr.get() is also "null".  

I tried several URLs passing to the cosntructor of ClientResource, didnt work either.  

Is there a different way to read a local file into tomcat servlet?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you thierry templier, your answer helped me and it works now.

The point that wasnt clear in the restlet documentation, especially on this page:

http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.0/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html

is that the war-protocol doesnt work properly when you define as init-param an org.restlet.component in your web.xml! Instead you must use an org.restlet.application!!!

I tried it out in several clean projects and the result was always the same - when you use component as entry point there will be trouble accessing the context.

Well thanks man!

Comment: Pleased to hear that! Thanks very much for the analysis! It's definitively a strange behavior. I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1059.